# how to sort 2D list by their quotients using python

Tags: list, python-2.7

my `list` goes like

```
a = [[-1,1],[4,3],[-4,5]]
```

and I want it to sort according to their quotients.
`a[x][0]` as dividend and `a[x][1]` as divisor

So sorted list should go like this:

```
a =[[-1,1],[-4,5],[4,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key` argument of [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0]/x[1])
[[-1, 1], [-4, 5], [4, 3]]
```

Also, check the [sorting mini-HowTo](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) of the wiki.